# Quickly open a file in cloud9 ide

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Found [list of keyboard shortcuts](https://c9.io/site/blog/2011/11/effective-code-editing-with-cloud9-ide/) for cloud9 ide. Most of them works good.

But this not working:

**Quickly open a file**. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> (Option-Shift-R on Mac) to open the open file dialog and search for any file within your project.

I use google chrome on windows 7.

Comment: That link doesn't seem to work any more (404), and this is the top hit in Google for "cloud 9 keyboard shortcuts." D'oh.

Answer (score 4):

This shortcut has been replaced by <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> on OS X and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> on PC.

Answer (score 0):

If you open **Help - Keyboard Shortcuts** menu in Cloud9 Ide you see a lot of shortcuts. Some of them don't work in google chrome, some of them don't work in Firefox. And there is no <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> in that list. So it is seemingly obsolete.